# How to load localstorage data in list view in sencha touch?

Tags: sencha-touch

How to load localstorage data in list view in sencha touch?

I have my model:

```
Ext.define('SenchaWebWorker.model.tweetsModel', {
extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
requires:['Ext.data.proxy.LocalStorage'],
config: {
    fields: [
    { name: 'id', type: 'string' },
    { name: 'text', type: 'string' },
    { name: 'date', type: 'string' },
    { name: 'uname', type: 'string' },
    { name: 'uid', type: 'string' },
    { name: 'uimgurl', type: 'string' }
    ],
    proxy: {
        type: 'localstorage',
        id  : '_tweetStore'
    }
}});
```

and my store:

```
Ext.define('SenchaWebWorker.store.tweetStore', {
extend: "Ext.data.Store",
config: {
    storeId: '_tweetStore',
    model: 'SenchaWebWorker.model.tweetsModel',
    autoLoad:true
}});
```

please give me some example if possibel.
Thanks.

Comment: http://docs-origin.sencha.com/touch/2.3.1/#!/api/Ext.data.proxy.LocalStorage .. this is not helpful ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's very easy to do, just simply reference your store in the config object of your list, i.e:

```
Ext.define('MyApp.view.MyList', {
extend: 'Ext.dataview.List',
xtype: 'MyList',
config: {
    store : 'MyStore',
    itemTpl : document.getElementById('tpl_my_list').innerHTML
}
});
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do is set store property of list to _tweetStore

```
Ext.define('SenchaWebWorker.view.tweetsList', {
    extend: 'Ext.List',
    xtype: 'tweetlist',
    config: {
           store:'_tweetStore',
           scrollable:true,
           scrollToTopOnRefresh:true,
           deselectOnContainerClick:true,       

           ............
           ............

    }
});
```

Since you have autoLoad set to true, no need to explicitly load store data.